# Photo Resize when loading... PHP photo from server

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if anyone could provide me with some advice on where I went wrong. I'm trying to get a photo to resize when loaded in a DIV but the photo keeps taking it's own dimensions. Does anyone have any idea why my code isn't working? Thank you in advance!

```
if($row['coverphoto'] === NULL){
                echo"<li>";
                echo"<img src='images/slider-4.jpg'>";
                    echo "<div class='banner'>Customize Your Banner!</div>";
                echo "</li>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<li>";
                echo "<img style='height:auto; width:auto; max-width:1025px; max-height:503px;' src='/coverphotos/" . $row['coverphoto'] . "'/><br />";
                 echo "<div class='banner'>Customize Your Banner!</div>";

                echo "</li>";
            }
                ?>
```

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean exactly, what happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: Photo expands to whatever it's properties are not the dimensions I've set.
Max-width and max-height don't work.

Comment: What happens if you use height and width instead of max-height and max-width?

Comment: @amenadiel same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        else{
            echo "<li>";
            echo "<div style="width:50px;height:50px;"><img style='height:50px; width:50px;' src='/coverphotos/" . $row['coverphoto'] . "'/></div><br />";
             echo "<div class='banner'>Customize Your Banner!</div>";

            echo "</li>";
        }
```

If it is not worked means, please check your, css file

```
 <li>
```

styles. May that style makes this mistake.